# How to combine regression tables in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, texreg

I am combining regression tables in `knitr`. I tried to using `texreg`, but it didn't work. What else can I do? Thanks. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<result='asis'>>=
  library(texreg)
  reg1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
  reg2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
  texreg(list(reg1,reg2))
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second call to `lm` overwrites the previous value of `reg`

`?texreg` says that the first argument can be "a `list` of statistical models", so try making a list.

```
texreg(list(lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris), 
            lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)))
```

Comment: see also the examples section of `?texreg`

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code, but the result is not shown in a table.

Comment: @Lin note it is `results` instead of `result`; please read the documentation more carefully: http://yihui.name/knitr/options

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or feature of the `texreg` package; you should probably talk to the author of `texreg`:

```
>   library(texreg)
Version:  1.15
Date:     2012-11-13
>   reg1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
>   reg2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
>   texreg(list(reg1,reg2))

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{3.5} @{}D{.}{.}{3.5} @{}}
\toprule
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2} \\
\midrule
(Intercept) & 1.08^{***} & 6.53^{***} \\
            & (0.07)     & (0.48)     \\
Petal.Width & 2.23^{***} &            \\
            & (0.05)     &            \\
Sepal.Width &            & -0.22      \\
            &            & (0.16)     \\
\midrule
R$^2$       & 0.93       & 0.01       \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.93       & 0.01       \\
Num. obs.   & 150        & 150        \\
\bottomrule
\vspace{-2mm}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{table}
[1] "\n\\usepackage{booktabs}\n\\usepackage{dcolumn}\n\n\\begin{table}\n\\begin{center}\n\\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{3.5} @{}D{.}{.}{3.5} @{}}\n\\toprule\n            & \\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} & \\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2} \\\\\n\\midrule\n(Intercept) & 1.08^{***} & 6.53^{***} \\\\\n            & (0.07)     & (0.48)     \\\\\nPetal.Width & 2.23^{***} &            \\\\\n            & (0.05)     &            \\\\\nSepal.Width &            & -0.22      \\\\\n            &            & (0.16)     \\\\\n\\midrule\nR$^2$       & 0.93       & 0.01       \\\\\nAdj. R$^2$  & 0.93       & 0.01       \\\\\nNum. obs.   & 150        & 150        \\\\\n\\bottomrule\n\\vspace{-2mm}\\\\\n\\multicolumn{3}{l}{\\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.01$, \n  \\textsuperscript{**}$p<0.05$, \n  \\textsuperscript{*}$p<0.1$}\n\\end{tabular}\n\\end{center}\n\\caption{Statistical models}\n\\label{table:coefficients}\n\\end{table}\n"
```

The problem is that `texreg()` prints the TeX table in the console and returns a *visible* character vector at the same time (see the last line above), while I guess the latter is unnecessary, although you can fix it by putting `invisible()` around `texreg()` or assign it to a variable to avoid printing. Here is a full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}

<<results='asis'>>=
library(texreg)
reg1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)
reg2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris)
invisible(texreg(list(reg1,reg2), use.packages=FALSE))
@

\end{document}
```

Also note you need `use.packages=FALSE` to avoid `\usepackage{dcolumn}` and `\usepackage{booktabs}` *in the middle* of the LaTeX document, which does not make sense (they should be in the preamble instead).